# jquery animated Line with animated gif from left to right loop

Tags: jquery, animation

I managed to make it work but i want the loop to be from left:0 to 100%. Imagine you have a circle and you make the effect start in one point and then the effect goes arround the circle until it starts again (loop).

```
<script>
$( window ).load(function() {
 (function loop(){
    $("#mark").animate({
    'marginLeft': '+=100%'
}, 5000);
$("#mark").animate({
    'marginLeft': '-=100%'
}, 5000, loop);
})();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably do something like

```
 (function loop(){
     // Reset position to original 0%
     $("#mark").css('marginLeft', '0%');

     // animate it to 100%
     $("#mark").animate({
        'marginLeft': '100%'
     }, 5000, loop);
     // call itself again after it's done (5000 ms)
  })();
```

inside your window load, you might even want to set the marginLeft to be -width of #mark, to make it seem like it's appearing from the side.

question though, why not use position + left, instead of margins?

Comment: works perfect:)... what if i want to star in 0 and fill the line from 0 to 100?

Comment: not sure what you mean by "star in 0, and fill the line from 0 to 100". Do you mean something like a progress bar, or loading animation? If so this is the top of my google search http://www.freshdesignweb.com/jquery-css3-loading-progress-bar.html

Comment: sorry i typed it wrong, something like a progress bar

Comment: done it... just change the 'marginLeft' for the 'width' lol :)